# Can I push al onto a stack in TASM?

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, tasm

I am a beginner in assembly and any help would be appreciated. Here is my code:

```
.MODEL SMALL

.DATA  
Textstring db "I'm a string$"
.CODE
START:

mov dx, Textstring
push dx
getche:
    mov ah, 06h
    int 21h
    push al



 END START
```

I keep getting the errors that operand types do not match on line 8 and argument to operation or instruction has illegal size on line 13.
I am guessing the problem is I am trying to push `AL` onto the stack. Is there anyway I could push the contents of `AL` onto the stack? I am trying to make a code where I prompt the user for a character and return that character back to the program that called it.

Comment: push the 16-bit register AX (which AL is the lower 8 bits). You don't give us context as to why you are attempting to put a byte on the stack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot push `AL` into the stack because every element of the stack is a **word** and `AL`'s size is a **byte**.

What you can do, is reset `AH`'s value and push `AX` into the stack so `AL` will contain the value you want and `AH` will just be 0 which will not affect the data in `AL`.

Comment: Or just push `ax` or `eax`, and later when you pop it ignore the garbage in the high byte(s).

Answer (score 1):

### You've asked about these 2 errors.

> operand types do not match on line 8

When you write `mov dx, Textstring` TASM will want to encode the operation of reading a byte from memory. It's a **byte** because you defined Textstring using the `db` directive. The error would not have existed, had you written

```
mov dl, Textstring
```

If you wanted to get a pointer to the text in Textstring, then you should write instead

```
mov dx, offset Textstring
```

> argument to operation or instruction has illegal size on line 13.

Neither `push` nor `pop` accept a byte sized operand. The architecture simply does not allow it.

To push the contents of a byte sized register (like `AL`), you just push the corresponding word sized register (`AX`).
Later when you `pop` this word sized data, you just ignore the part that did not contain the useful value. This might require you to carefully choose the register to pop into!